# Unix batch job execution from BDD automation framework

Tags: java, selenium, unix, automation, cucumber

As part of my testing, I have to connect to Unix server using putty and execute few unix jobs.

Feature file
Steps for test scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Job execution in Unix
Given I logged into unix server
When I navigate to job directory "<job_directory_path>" and submit the job "<job>"
Then I validate job run status code
And close the session

Examples: data@jobs.xlsx:jobs
| | | | |

snapshot of excelsheet jobs.xlsx
|jobdirectorypath|jobname|
|/com/home/joblist|QAWAS12|
|/com/home/joblist|QAWAS13|
```

Step definition file

```
@Given("^I logged into unix server$")
    public void i_logged_into_unix_server() throws Throwable {
        try{
             Unixcon ucon = new Unixcon.getInstance();
             uc.con_to_unix();
             System.out.println("connected");
           }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
 
    }

    @When("^I navigate to job directory \"([^\"]*)\" and submit the job \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_navigate_to_job_directory_something_and_submit_the_job_something(String jobdirectorypath, String jobname) throws Throwable {
        try{
             Unixcon ucon = new Unixcon.getInstance();
             uc.execute_job(jobdirectorypath, jobname);
             System.out.println("job executed:"+jobname);
           }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

    @Then("^I validate job run status code$")
    public void i_validate_job_run_status_code() throws Throwable {
        try{
             Unixcon ucon = new Unixcon.getInstance();
             String status_code = String.valueOf(ucon.ch.getExitStatus());
             if(status_code == 0){
             System.out.println("Passed");
             write_to_excel("status",status_code,"Passed");
             }else{
             System.out.println("Failed");
             write_to_excel("status",status_code,"Failed");
   
           }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

    @And("^close the session$")
    public void close_the_session() throws Throwable {
       try{
             Unixcon ucon = new Unixcon.getInstance();
             ucon.close_session();
             System.out.println("closed");
             
           }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
           }

        
    }
```

Unixcon.JAVA

```
public class Unixcon{

public JSch jsch =null;
public Session session = nulll;
public Channel ch =null;
String host = TestProperty.getProperty("HOSTNAME");
String username = TestProperty.getProperty("USERNAME");
String password = TestProperty.getProperty("PASSWORD");
int port = TestProperty.getProperty("PORT");

private static Unixcon ucon;

public static Unixcon getInstatnce(){
  if(ucon==null){
  ucon = new Unixcon();
  }
 return ucon;
}

private Unixcon(){
 super();
}

public void con_to_unix(){

try{
jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(username,host,port);
session.setpassword(password);
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setconfig(p);
session.connect();
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

public void execute_job(String jobdirectorypath, String jobname){
try{
ch = session.OpenChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) ch).setCommand("cd" + jobdirectorypath +" && ./" + jobname);
ch.connect();
InputStrem in = ch.getInputStream();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String l = "";
while((l=r.readLine()) != null){
System.out.println(l);
}
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStachTrace();
}
}

public void close_session() {
try{
 if(session != null)
{
ch.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStachTrace();
}
}
}
```

Is my implementation approch correct? Please provide your suggestions for code improvement.

Comment: Methods initialise variables called "ucon" then attempt method calls on "uc". If the OP won't present compiled and tested code, why should we review it?

Comment: @dariosicily [Only the OP is allowed to edit the code in the question.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/762) As such I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Thank you for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my implementation approch correct?

You mean, your implementation of `Unixcon.JAVA` ? Then if it works as expected it may be correct but I doubt because there are some typos and invalid syntax in your code:

### Strange errors

*(that looks like you have not done your homework)*

- The test do a `new Unixcon.getInstance()`. Which is invalid because

  1. The constructor is private, so you cannot create any instance outside of the class.
  2. There are no parentheses in your constructor

  -> If you want to call a static method, you should do `Unixcon.getInstance()`
- The test use `getInstance()` while your class declare `getInstatnce()`

  -> Align your names, compile and test your code before posting it.
- Missing brackets, the `if` in `close_session` has an unbalanced bracket.

Anyway, there are some possible improvements:

### Singleton

- Your `Unixcon` is a singleton this means that you cannot run two processes in parallel without running in troubles.
- Your singleton may not be unique; there are many articles explaining how to get one unique instance.

### Naming

- Java use *lowerCamelCase* for methods names. Rename to `conToUnix`, `executeJob`, etc...

### OO Design

- Use encapsulation to hide the implementation details. Don't expose `Channel ch` but provide an accessor to `getExitStatus()`
- Pass the `TestProperty` so that you can easily connect to another host or use another means to get those values.

That's a personal opinion, but what about having a non singleton connection object that return a `JobExecution` when you run a job ?

```
/* Allow many instances and use an ssh style connection string 
 * to clarify your code. But keep another constructor that takes
 * all parameters independently.
 *
 * The UnixConnection implements AutoCloseable for a simpler code
 */  
try(UnixConnection connection = new UnixConnection("user@hostname:port", password)) {         
  JobExecution result = connection.execute("jobname", inDirectory);
  /* isSuccessful is a simple test on the exit status, but clarify 
   * the intention much more than `== 0`. 
   * Alternatively you may want to throw a `JobExceutionError` 
   * instead of playing with a status. */
  if ( result.isSuccessful() ) {
    result.getJobName();
    result.getStatus();
    result.getOutputStream(); // Or a String or an Collection/Stream/Iterable<String>
  }
}
```